# When will waypointPushpinOptions be available in Bing Maps v8 release branch?

Tags: bing-maps

I use the following code while calculating directions and displaying a route on a map.

```
directionsManager.setRenderOptions({
  autoUpdateMapView: false,
  displayRouteSelector: false,
  waypointPushpinOptions: {
    visible: false
  }
});
```

If I use the experimental branch everything is fine and the route as well as the custom pushpins are displayed as desired:
[image]

With the use of the release branch script the following map with doubled pushpins and additional information - that's unwanted - is rendered:[image]

When will the changes in the experimental branch be released? Is there another workaround instead of using the experimental branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is already available, however the visible option is not yet supported. All other options are though. The visible option should be working in the experimental either now or very soon and will be added to the main release branch in the next update.